# Typescript constraints not validated

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why do neither my TS linter nor compiler complain about the type massacre in my `test` method here? It appears that the `item: T` constraint isn't validated at all.

Tested on TS 3.8.3 and an old 3.2.2:

```
export class Foo {}

export class Bar {}

export class FooBar {
    test() {
        const thisIsNotABar: Bar = this.echo<Bar>(new Foo());
    }

    echo<T>(item: T): T {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Foo and Bar are compatible (their definitions are identical). Try adding a property to one that isn't in the other and TypeScript should give you an error:

```
export class Foo { a: any }

export class Bar { b: any }

export class FooBar {
    test() {
        const thisIsNotABar: Bar = this.echo<Bar>(new Foo());
    }

    echo<T>(item: T): T {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Gives the error:

> Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bar'.
>     Property 'b' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Bar'.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, welcome to TypeScript's [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#introduction).  In TypeScript, two types are the same if they have the same *shape* or *structure*.  It does not depend on the *name* or *declaration* of the types, as in [nominal type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) you might be more used to in other languages.

So, even though your `Foo` and `Bar` have different *names* and different *declarations*, they have the same *shape* and *structure*; namely that of an [empty object type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  And so, in TypeScript, `Foo` and `Bar` are exactly the same type.

If you want `Foo` and `Bar` to be considered distinct, you should add some incompatibility of *structure*, such as giving them different properties:

```
export class Foo {
    foo = ""
}

export class Bar {
    bar = ""
}
```

If you do that, the error you expected should happen:

```
    const thisIsNotABar: Bar = this.echo<Bar>(new Foo()); // error!
    // Foo is not assignable to Bar
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DEITgbwFgAoOMuAM1zgF44AiekgXxLhNElkVQzgCEUUAm3IAjIbQZNirYh3DR4ydJhwRBwoqXIxgaGAAoAlCJ3lyCCADsDcGAAsAlmgCSaAHIQYAQU0AuAUk6RxcAOmAEBwgAHk0APkNrYAB3bFwTYwBuOAB6XLhgKChoAEJRMjkKwqjYgBVEpz0AW0C64zazCwsoYBgAVyhrOCbgZqzquWYgA)

Comment: nice one! thanks for the quick and well-written reply!